# Could not find a declaration file for module chartjs-plugin-stacked100

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js

I am trying to use `chartjs-plugin-stacked100` in a React App:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import ChartjsPluginStacked100 from 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100';

const ConnectedTime = () => {
  // https://designcode.io/react-hooks-handbook-usestate-hook
  // https://designcode.io/react-hooks-handbook-fetch-data-from-an-api
  useEffect(() => {   }, []);
  return <>
      {
    <div>
        <ChartjsPluginStacked100
          type="bar"
          data={{
            labels: ["Foo", "Bar"],
            datasets: [
              { label: "bad", data: [5, 25], backgroundColor: "rgba(244, 143, 177, 0.6)" },
              { label: "better", data: [15, 10], backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.6)},
              { label: "good", data: [10, 8], backgroundColor: "rgba(100, 181, 246, 0.6)" }]    
          }}
          options={{ 
            indexAxis: "y",
            plugins: {
              stacked100: { enable: true }
            }
          }} />
    </div>
      }
  </>
}

export default ConnectedTime
```

When I `yarn start` this piece of code, I get the error:

```
TypeScript error in /home/mihamina/.../src/Components/ConnectedTime/ConnectedTime.tsx(4,37):
Could not find a declaration file for module 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100'. 
'/home/mihamina/.../node_modules/chartjs-plugin-stacked100/build/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/chartjs-plugin-stacked100` if it exists 
or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing 
`declare module 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100';`
```

Issuing `npm i --save-dev @types/chartjs-plugin-stacked100` : The package does not exist.

I dont quite understand about the `.d.ts` file:

- Do I create it at the root of the project? (same folder as `package.json`?)
- Is the required name really `.d.ts` or should I prepend the name with `chartjs-plugin-stacked100`?
- 

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work:

- Create a `global.d.ts` and declare the module
- Use the `Bar` component

Content of  `global.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100';

declare module 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100'{
    export function ChartjsPluginStacked100(): function
}
```

Use of `Bar`:

```
import { Chart, Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import ChartjsPluginStacked100 from 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100';

Chart.register(ChartjsPluginStacked100);

const ChartData = (props: any) => {
    return <>
    {
      <div>
        <Bar
          data={{
            labels: ["Foo", "Bar"],
            datasets: [
              { label: "bad", data: [5, 25], backgroundColor: "rgba(244, 143, 177, 0.6)" },
              { label: "better", data: [15, 10], backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.6)" },
              { label: "good", data: [10, 8], backgroundColor: "rgba(100, 181, 246, 0.6)" }]
          }}
          options={{
            indexAxis: "y",
            plugins: {
              stacked100: { enable: true }
            }
          }} />
      </div>
    }
</>
};
export default ChartData
```

I updated the documentation and requested a pull at: https://github.com/y-takey/chartjs-plugin-stacked100/pull/48 , where I wrote a small sample React app that uses the plugin.

Comment: Thanks to your fix, now it is able to find the module declaration. However, I'm getting the error "Unable to resolve path to module 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100'" on the import of the plugin ChartjsPluginStacked100 now. Do you have any idea how to fix this ?