# Unable to resolve path to module 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am currently working on `chart.js` with `react-chart-js-2`.
My `package.json` includes the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
        "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
        "chartjs-plugin-stacked100": "^1.0.4",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^3.3.0",
        "typescript": "^3.9.5",
        ...
    },
```

And the following dev dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.0",
        "eslint": "^7.29.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.4.0",
        ...
    }
```

I would like to display a chart with stacked bars, that take 100% of the space, and I found this plugin that does exactly the job: [chartjs-plugin-stacked100](https://github.com/y-takey/chartjs-plugin-stacked100) (you can find a working demo [here](https://y-takey.github.io/chartjs-plugin-stacked100/)).
However, when I want to use this plugin in my react app (using `typescript`, by the way), I got some errors.

I install the plugin using the following command:
`npm install chartjs-plugin-stacked100 --save`

Then in a `.tsx` file, I'm trying to import the plugin :
`import ChartjsPluginStacked100 from "chartjs-plugin-stacked100";`
The import is failing, with the following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100'. 'c:/Users/Nutzer/Documents/git/Infinite-UI/node_modules/chartjs-plugin-stacked100/build/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/chartjs-plugin-stacked100` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100';
```

There is no such package for the types sadly.
But thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69048899/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-chartjs-plugin-stacked100) post in Stack Overflow, I created a file `global.d.ts` at the root of my `src` folder, and added the following code inside :

```
declare module 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100';

declare module 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100'{
    export function ChartjsPluginStacked100(): function
}
```

And now, I am getting the following error on the import of the plugin:
`Unable to resolve path to module 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100'.`

So I can't use this plugin, because I can't import it correctly. Am I doing something wrong?

I tried to create a reproducible example on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-wozniak-z4tlg), which is actually working( I even added my `tsconfig.json` and my `eslintrc.json`, because I thought it could have cause this issue).

Do you have any hint about this failing import ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my error was caused by my `eslintrc` configuration. So I just had to add this in the `.eslintrc.json` (in the root of my `src` folder):

```
"settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "node": {
                "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
              }
        }
    }
```

So now I am able to import the js module